# Put latitude and longitude on a mapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I tried to show the place that I want in mapView by insering latitude and longitude, but I failed to do that and the map show me always my place where I am and not the place that I want to get

these is the code that I used

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.showsPointsOfInterest = true
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        //user location stuff
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.1070, longitude: -112.1130)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment this

```
map.showsUserLocation = true
```

And put the code of `didUpdateLocations` inside `viewDidLoad`

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.showsPointsOfInterest = true
        //map.showsUserLocation = true
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        //user location stuff
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.1070, longitude: -112.1130)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
         ///
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I have to put this function inside viewDidLoad?                                                                func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 36.1070, longitude: -112.1130)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    }

Comment: I do that and when I set my place coordinate it show me the place,but when I put the coordinate of another place it didn't give me any thing.

Answer (score 0):

To have a more reliable and efficient result,

I recommend using .plist (property list) file to store the latitude and longitude *dynamically* it would be much easier and would cost you less time.
plist contains the pins annotation directions which are basically an XML text file that holds the essential configuration information for bundle execution.
here is how to attach it to your project:
In your main view controller write the function:

```
    func fetchAllData(){

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NAME OF YOUR PLIST FILE", ofType: "plist") {
        ////If your plist contain root as Dictionary
        if let dic = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: Any] {

            let keys=dic.keys

            for dataOfKey in keys {
                if let object=dic[dataOfKey] as? [[String:Any]]{

                    locationsArray.append(contentsOf: object)
                }
            }
        }

        for location in self.locationsArray{

            let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
            newPin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: Double(location["latitude"] as! String)!, longitude: Double(location["longitude"] as! String)!)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)

        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I will test it